# How does Html.AntiForgeryToken protects against an POST with preceding GET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, security, csrf

Ok, I hope I am missing a point here.

Since long, MVC has a `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` helper to insert a token into a form to protect the form being submitted from another web-site. (CSRF)

The helper will produce a hidden input, something like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="cXnXkzw2..." name="__RequestVerificationToken">
```

Which is known at the server side, and used to validate the `POST`. Sounds good.

However, if a person would put effort in scripting an attack, which uses the authentication cookie of the website and a malicious `POST`, how hard would it be to perform a preceding `GET` first to retrieve this hidden input `AntiForgeryToken` and use it in the `POST`?

In other words; how does the `AntiForgeryToken` helps here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is, it doesn't.

The Anti-Forgery Tokens (One as a cookie & the other as a hidden form field) are not supposed to be accessible to a malicious page/attacker due to the same origin policy. This means that an attacker cannot access content on another site.

If it is accessible then this totally compromises the tokens and they become redundant. What you're suggesting could potentially happen if cross-domain has been enabled.

I hope this answers your question Stefan.

Comment: Ah, so besides the authentication cookie, there is a cookie (or the same authentication cookie) which contain information about the token value... that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah - The server will validate both tokens on the server.

Comment: Is it safe for IFrames as well then? (I'll have to admit; I am not that experienced with IFrames)

Comment: Iframes work the same way as requests are still made to a different domain and will block attackers from requesting content due to cross domain restrictions. Therefore the tokens will not be exposed.